# How to run Jasmine tests in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, jasmine, phantomjs

We have been writing specifications for our JavaScript business logic using [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/). We're able to run our test suite within a browser, but how would we integrate this within TeamCity? Preferrably we do not want to use NodeJS, rather something as simple as possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have created a modified version of `run-jasmine.js` that is found in the [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) sources (original version is [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/run-jasmine.js). This version can be used within TeamCity (it will automatically detect that it is running in TeamCity). This updated version is using TeamCity [service messages](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity) which allows for a nice integration.

You will need [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org). You'll also need one of the following:

- [run-jasmine.js](https://gist.github.com/dlidstrom/8432345) (for Jasmine 1.x).
- [run-jasmine.js](https://gist.github.com/barahilia/9663804) (for Jasmine 2.x).

Add a build step in your TeamCity build configuration that can run this step:

```
phantomjs.exe run-jasmine.js index.html
```

`index.html` is your Jasmine runner page. If the build agents do not include PhantomJS, you can commit it to your repository along with your sources (this is what we do).

The result will look like this:

[image: Tests Overview]

Test details:
[image: Test Details]

The above is from a [Tasks](https://github.com/dlidstrom/Tasks) sample ASP.NET MVC project with this setup. It can be run in TeamCity using a Visual Studio (sln) build step. It will also run the tests within Visual Studio, as a pre-build step.

Comment: Daniel - thank you for the script and the explanation. Worked for me almost instantly. 2 quirks I had: Jasmine runs files from a different folder with "/folder/file.js" syntax, while Phantom apparently requires "../folder/file.js". And it wasn't clear that Team City needs command line build step.

Comment: @IliaBarahovski Yes, the current working directory could be different from one solution to another, depending on how you setup your directories. Anyway, nice to hear you got it working!

Comment: @DanielLidström  - Thanks for your clarification. But I could not able to run the jasmine tests in teamcity. Added the phantomjs.exe and run-jasmine.js from the link which is provided there. If possible provide a link ,if you are having any sample source or GIT link.

Comment: @PandiyanCool Here is a complete sample: https://github.com/dlidstrom/Tasks. I am able to build it continuously using a Solution build step within TeamCity, and the tests are run automatically as a pre-build step. Let me know how this works out for you.

Comment: @DanielLidström - Thanks once again. I was able to run jasmine tests for sample application in teamcity.But in my application, I am using knockout.js, require,js, So that I was getting "Reference Error: Can't find variable: jasmine".
Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.body.querySelector('.alert > .passingAlert.bar').innerText')
phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():58
phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():61
phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():61
Could you help me out with that please?

Comment: @PandiyanCool - I'm guessing that you're using Jasmine 2.0 and not 1.3 which is the version this `run-jasmine.js` file is written for. It's failing to pull out the html element with the selector `.alert > .passingAlert.bar` because that's now been replaced by `.alert > .bar` in 2.0. There is a forked version of the runner for version 2.0 here https://gist.github.com/barahilia/9663804

Comment: love the implementation. I have added example with for team city config : https://gist.github.com/cpoDesign/a72845a4c703793bdaab